# Define a const in class constructor (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way I can define a `const` in the constructor of a class?

I tried this:

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {
        const bar = 42;
    }

    getBar = () => {
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```

But

```
var a = new Foo();
console.log ( a.getBar() );
```

returns undefined.

Comment: @Bergi Not even remotely similar to what I'm asking.

Comment: Well [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object) explains the difference between variables and properties, with which you seem to have problems. Admittedly, it doesn't tell it you how to define nonwritable properties.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You use static read-only properties to declare constant values that are scoped to a class.

```
class Foo {
    static get BAR() {
        return 42;
    }
}

console.log(Foo.BAR); // print 42.
Foo.BAR = 43; // triggers an error
```

Comment: Actually, the `=>` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @alexandernst thanks.

Comment: JS is so workaroundy.

Answer (score 8):

Simply defining a constant in the constructor won't attach it to the instance, you have to set it using `this`. I'm guessing you want immutability, so you can use [getters](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#getters_and_setters):

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {
        this._bar = 42;
    }

    get bar() {
        return this._bar;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like you normally would:

```
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar) // 42
foo.bar = 15;
console.log(foo.bar) // still 42
```

This will not throw an error when trying to change `bar`. You could raise an error in a setter if you want:

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {
        this._bar = 42;
    }

    get bar() {
        return this._bar;
    }

    set bar(value) {
        throw new Error('bar is immutable.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with "bar" scoping - it scoped to constructor:

```
'use strict';

class Foo {
    constructor () {
        const bar = 42;
        this.bar = bar; // scoping to the class 
    }

    getBar () {
      return this.bar;
    }
}

var a = new Foo();
console.log ( a.getBar() );
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Doing it this way, the properties of `const` are maintained, right?

Comment: @alexandernst - no, `this.bar` will not be a constant, and can be overwritten

Comment: Then what is the point of `const` at all if it can't be used in a class?

Comment: I'm writing another answer which might be closer to what you want…

Comment: @alexandernst the `const` keyword is a immutable version of `var` and has all the same scope issues as `var`.

Comment: You can create a non-writable property that can't be overwritten inside the object like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/vestfr1v/), but the returned primitive `42` will still be overwritable