# React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to play different sound with each button. And I try to access the sound url from array variable with passed index number

I pass index number with key in playSound function then I try to get url from const piano variable it throws an error in console. what I am doing wrong here ?

```js
let { Button, ButtonToolbar, ButtonGroup, Radio, DropdownButton, MenuItem } = ReactBootstrap;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        power: true,
        instrument: 'piano',
        buttonColor:true,
    };
    this.playSound = this.playSound.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.changeColor =this.changeColor.bind(this);
    

const piano = [{
    keyCode: 81,
    keyTrigger: 'Q',
    id: 'Heater-1',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3'
  }, {
    keyCode: 87,
    keyTrigger: 'W',
    id: 'Heater-2',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3'
  }, {
    keyCode: 69,
    keyTrigger: 'E',
    id: 'Heater-3',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3'
  }, 
];
  
  changeColor(){
    this.setState({buttonColor: !this.state.buttonColor})
  }
  
  playSound(key){
    if (this.state.power == true) {
      this.audio = new Audio(this.piano[key].url)
      this.audio.play();
      this.changeColor();
      setTimeout(() => this.changeColor(), 200 ) 
    }
  };
  
  toggle() {
    this.setState({ 
      power: !this.state.power,
    });
    console.log(!this.state.power)
    
  };
  
  render(){
    let btn_style = this.state.buttonColor ? 'primary' : 'warning'
    return(
    <div id='container' >
      <div className='buttons' >
        <div className='firstLine'>
          <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button bsStyle= {btn_style} className='drum-pad' bsSize="large" onClick = {() => this.playSound(0)} >Q</Button>
            <Button bsStyle= {btn_style} className='drum-pad' bsSize="large" onClick = {() => this.playSound(1)} >W</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary" className='drum-pad' bsSize="large">E</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: the exact code you posted is not syntactically correct. You cant have `const` in the middle of a class like that. if you just change `const piano =` to `piano =` (remove const) it should work, because then your class will have a property `piano` that you can access with `this.piano`. also your constructor is missing a closing brace

Comment: I tried and now I receive an error of piano is not defined. const piano is defined inside the constructor. I also moved it outside of class and also constructor but again receive the same error.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use an editor that supports syntax highlighting for javascript and ideally react to prevent simple syntactical mistakes like that. Especially in javascript it is easy to miss a closing bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have missed the ending `}` of constructor after `piano`.

You cannot declare a const variable in the constructor to use it later by accessing it like `this.piano`. To know more about that check out this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242113/define-a-const-in-class-constructor-es6).

So, declare it like a variable like you did for `state`.

Just change your `const piano = [];` to  `this.piano = [];`.

It should work.

Comment: Thank you I was about to get crazy :) BTW It was because of const piano I changed it to this.piano and it worked.